# Where can I just download the entire blockchain data folder after install Mist?

Tags: blockchain, synchronization

I'm running Mist for linux and its taking awhile to download the entire blockchain. Is there a place I can just download the entire blockchain folder and just copy it into the /resources folder in the mist folder?

Also where can I specify where to place my /resources folder? Say I want to only download it to my network drive only instead of on my small laptop hard drive.